# Проекты С++ в VS 2022 очень долго запускаются

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Любой даже малейший код в пару строк запускается по 5 минут ровно и выдает будто есть какой-то сбой в программе(в консоль все выводит верно). День назад все запускалось за секунду и никаких сбоев в том же самом коде не было, ПК у меня нормальный: 16 оперативы, проц ryzen 5 4600h, пробовал переустановить VS, не помогло. Подскажите, что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Вирусов нету, проверял антивируской iobit malware figther pro, а насчет сбоя то в логах про него ничего не пишет (может я не так проверяю, не могли бы вы сказать как узнать в чем именно сбой), он присутствует в любом коде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я имею ввиду что оно выводит это, а самих ошибок в коде нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прямо сейчас еще выдало вот эту ошибку, до этого ее не было, я ничего не менял за это время.

Вывод:

```
Сборка начата… 
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Project1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Отменена задача. 
1>Отменена задача. 
========== Сборка: успешно выполнено — 0 , со сбоем — 1, в актуальном состоянии — 0, пропущено — 0 ========== 
========== Сборка запущено в 13:22, заняло 05:00,926 мин ==========
```

Comment: Проверить комп на вирусы. Подобные сбои характерны для вредоносных программ.

Comment: *"выдает будто есть какой-то сбой в программе"* - приводите этот вывод в вопросе

Comment: Вы не поняли. Приведите _текст ошибки_. Без него мы ничего не поймем.

Comment: Ну вот есть [статья по вашей проблеме](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/the-system-cannot-find-the-specified-path/#:~:text=The%20Windows%20error%20“The%20system,cleaning%20up%20the%20update%20files)

Comment: Ваша ошибка означает лишь, что код не собрался, и поэтому невозможно запустить программу. Вам нужно показать вывод от процесса сборки, он отображается под редактором кода. Возможно, со вкладки "Ошибки" нужно переключиться на "Вывод", а затем выбрать вывод от сборки.

Comment: Сборка начата…
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Project1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Отменена задача.
1>Отменена задача.
========== Сборка: успешно выполнено — 0 , со сбоем — 1, в актуальном состоянии — 0, пропущено — 0 ==========
========== Сборка запущено в 13:22, заняло 05:00,926 мин ==========

Comment: Попробуйте решения из этого вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26256957/8674428

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: пока-что перешёл на версию vs 2019, там проблем не наблюдаеться